# Unable to insert a number at a given array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

Could somebody please explain to me why my code doesn't work?

It should place the second arg (`3`) between arr (`[1,5]`). But the only thing JS tells me is "3".

```
function where(arr, num){
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] < num){
        slice(arr[i+1,0,num])
    }
    else if(arr[i] > num){
        slice(arr[i+1,0,num])
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
where = ([1, 5],3);
```

Please know, I just started JS, so my knowledge is limited. 
Any suggestions or help is very appreciated.

Comment: Should we assume the array is ordered? Why do you overwrite `where`? What is `slice`? How is `slice` supposed to modify `arr` if it doesn't receive any reference to it? Maybe you mean `arr.slice`?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Put `num` in correct position assuming that the array is ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems here.

1. Methods must be called via the array. i.e. `arr.slice()` whereas `slice(...)` will throw an error.
2. `slice` does not add to an array. It removes from the array. You'll need to use `splice`.
3. Using a `for` loop here like you do is not the best approach because it will keep going after you insert the element. Essentially, you want to insert the element into an ordered list? If so, exit the function with `return` as soon as you insert the element or use `break`.

Your function could look like this:

```
function where (arr, num) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > num) {
      // Inserts num at i
      arr.splice(i, 0, num);
      return arr;
    }
  }
  // If it's the highest num, add to the end of the array.
  arr.push(num);
  return arr;
}

var newArray = where([1, 5], 3);
```

However, your question is a little ambiguous, so if you're trying to insert an element at a specific index, you can just use splice directly:

```
var arr = [1, 5];
// Inserts 3 at index of 1
arr.splice(1, 0, 3);
// arr becomes [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! You really helped me out here.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you're set, you should accept an answer so people know this question has been answered sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but :

- I don't think the "slice" function does what you expect ; you should call it on the Array, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice), and it returns a *new* array, so you have to assign the result to something
- However, The reason you only see (`3`) is because you never call the `ẁhere` function that you define. Instead, you are computing the value of `([1,5],3)`, and affecting it to a new global variable called `where`.

The reason why `([1,5],3)` has value "3" is because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/L_op%C3%A9rateur_virgule). Basically :

```
([1,5],3)
```

is the same as

```
[1,5],3
```

which evaluates both `[1,5]` and `3`, and return the last evaluated value (`3`)

Try changing the last line to an actual function call :

```
var result = where([1, 5],3);
```

You'll get errors because of how you called slice ; hopefully with the doc you should see how to make it work.

Also, as pointed elsewhere, `slice` might not be the function you want to call in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: You're welcome ! As pointed elsewhere, don't hesitate to mark one of the answers as "Accepted", rather than using "Thank you" comments ! (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17886 for a discussion of that.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like a [dichotomic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search) and `arr.splice` at the right position:

```js
function insertItemInOrderedArray(arr, item, from, to) {
  if(from === undefined) from = 0;
  if(to === undefined) to = arr.length;
  if(from >= to) return arr.splice(from, 0, item), arr;
  var m = (from + to) / 2 | 0;
  if(arr[m] > item) return insertItemInOrderedArray(arr, item, from, m);
  if(arr[m] < item) return insertItemInOrderedArray(arr, item, m+1, to);
  return arr;
}
insertItemInOrderedArray([1,5], 3); // [1,3,5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!